# Pascal's Triangle|Leetcode Wrong Answer

Tags: c++, algorithm, pascals-triangle

https://leetcode.com/problems/pascals-triangle/

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> generate(int numRows) {
        vector<vector<int>> ret;
        for (int i=0; i<numRows; i++) {
            vector<int> v;
            if (i==0) {
            v.push_back(1);
            } else {
                v.push_back(1) ;
                for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
                    v.push_back(ret[i-1][j] + ret[i-1][j+1]);
                }
            }
            ret.push_back(v);
        }
        return ret;
    }
};
```

When I run the custom testcase:

```
Input: 3
Output: [[1],[1,1],[1,2,1]]
Expected: [[1],[1,1],[1,2,1]]
```

But it couldn't accepted. Submission Result is Wrong Answer:

```
Input: 3
Output: [[1],[1,32753],[1,32754,36704997]]
Expected: [[1],[1,1],[1,2,1]]
```

Could anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Run it through a debugger and **see** what is happening.

Comment: Thanks I rewrite my code and it was accepted.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when `i` is `1`?

```
if (i==0)
{...}
else
{
    v.push_back(ret[i-1][j] + ret[i-1][j+1]);
}
```

`ret[0]` has one element in it, but `ret[i-1][j+1]` accesses the second element. It's probably reading some garbage memory that was there and throwing your calculations off.

I would recommend padding the triangle with `1`s on the sides like so:

```
  1 1 1
 1 1 1 1
1 1 2 1 1
```

This way the edges don't read in uninitialized memory.